# httpClient.PostAsync crashes app in Xamarin Android JobService

Tags: android, xamarin, post, jobservice

I have an Android Xamarin app that handles notifications. When a notification is displayed, there are buttons that ask for a response. The app needs to send this response back to a server via an httpClient.PostAsync call. I am using the same http client wrapper in other parts of the code and it is working correctly. However, when I call it from the JobService code, the app crashes. I have enclosed the http call in a try/catch and no exception occurs. There are also no errors in the device log. i would like to know how to debug this. Here is my flow:

I have a class that derives from FirebaseMessagingService with an OnMessageReceived method. That gets called when a notification arrives. I build a local notification via the notification manager and call .Notify. The notification appears with the buttons. I have a BroadcastReceiver with an OnReceive method. That method schedules a job to do the post back of the button click. The job gets started and runs until the point I call the PostAsync. From there it crashes with no exception. Here is the relevant part of the JobWorker:

```
        public override bool OnStartJob(JobParameters jobParams)
        {
            _backgroundWorker = Task.Run(() => { DoWork(jobParams); });
            return true;
        }

        private void DoWork(JobParameters jobParams)
        {
            var logger = App.ResolveDependency<ILogger>() as ILogger;
            var callActions = App.ResolveDependency<ICallActionsHandler>() as ICallActionsHandler;

            var callToken = jobParams.Extras.GetString(JobParameterCallToken);
            var subsciberPhoneNumber = jobParams.Extras.GetString(JobParameterSubscriberPhoneNumber);
            var action = jobParams.Extras.GetString(JobParametersCallAction);

            logger.TraceInfo($"starting {nameof(CallActionService)}: starting job {jobParams.JobId}");
            callActions.SendAction(
                callToken,
                subsciberPhoneNumber,
                (CallActions)Enum.Parse(typeof(CallActions), action));
        }
```

The SendAction code calls the http client wrapper. The http client wrapper code looks like this:

```
        public async Task<int> PostAsync(string api, object message)
        {
            var apiUrl = Constants.DefaultAppApi + api;
            var contentText = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message);
            var content = new StringContent(contentText, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var backOff = 10;
            var retryCount = 5;
            HttpResponseMessage response = null;

            for (var attempt = 1; attempt <= retryCount; attempt++)
            {
                _logger.TraceInfo($"DataServerClient Post message: {message.GetType().Name}, attempt = {attempt}");
                try
                {
                   response = await _client.PostAsync(apiUrl, content);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    if (attempt == retryCount)
                        _logger.TraceException($"DataServerClient Post failed", ex);
                }

                if (response != null && response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    _logger.TraceInfo($"DataServerClient post was successful at retry count: {attempt}");
                    break;
                }

                backOff *= 2;
                await Task.Delay(backOff);
            }

            return (int)response.StatusCode;
        }
```

Can anyone provide clues for why this is failing or how I can gather diagnostics to find out what is happening? As I mentioned, the exception is not caught, the task that I create gets marked as completed, and no message gets posted.

Comment: I would suggest you add a try-catch to your HttpClient Wrapper, Secondly, I would suggest you read the output window thoroughly and look for clues. We at least need an exception to understand what's wrong otherwise all we would be doing is speculating!!!

Comment: there is a try/catch around the _client.PostAsync call. It does not catch the problem though.

Comment: Please use foreground service to make a test. If you want to execute some get/post request in the background. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/foreground-services . And JobService will not execute the task immediately.